# java.lang.ClassCastException,Getting Entitymanager Via JNDI Lookup

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, jdbc, jndi

I am new to JPA and developing a webapp(J2EE) where the webapp is in Tomcat so I can't use @PersistenceContext. I decided to use a Helper class and everything was going fine. Then I decided to implement JNDI for connection pooling and I managed to get Datasource.

The Helper Class looks like the following:

```
try {
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    entityManager =                                   //class cast exception
        (EntityManager)initCtx.lookup(
            "java:/comp/env/jdbc/LCDS"
        );
    DataSource ds= (DataSource)initCtx.lookup(
            "java:/comp/env/jdbc/LCDS"
    ); 
    System.out.println(ds.getConnection()+"Cool");
    //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXXXXX, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC  DriverCool
    emf=(EntityManagerFactory) source.getConnection();      //class cast exception
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XXXX");   //working version
}
```

The error is:

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong. I am not able to get EntityManagerFactory or EntityManager via JNDI lookup. I tried @Resource(name="jdbc/LCDS") and @PersistenceUnit(name="jdbc/LCDS").

Comment: Why do you do two calls to the same JNDI element and expect the result to be instances of different classes each time? Check the Tomcat manual to see how a `PersistenceUnit` is deployed to it.

Comment: `emf=(EntityManagerFactory) source.getConnection()` - here you are getting connection not EMF, so class cast is correct. Why just not use: `@PersistenceUnit(name="UNITNAME") EntityManagerFactory emf;` Unitname is from persistence.xml, it is not datasource jndi name.

Comment: emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UNIT NAME") and from emf i am able to get Entitymanager....then how do we use JNDI in jpa and where...???

Comment: You could try: `emf = (EntityManagerFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/UNIT NAME");`

Comment: Should i need to change jdbc/LCDS to jdbc/MyMyPersistenceUnitName...in(Context.xml)also...if not i tried with jdbc/MyMyPersistenceUnitName Or persistence/MyMyPersistenceUnitName

Comment: Name [persistence/MyMyPersistenceUnitName] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [persistence]. same error with jdbc/LCDS :(

Comment: It will not work in Tomcat, sorry. See my answer update.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
JNDI access to persistence unit is not possible due to Tomcat limitations. See [JPA Tomcat limitations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Limitations_to_JPA). You will have to use `emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UNIT NAME")`.
Sorry for misleading answer. I've tested that on WebSphere Liberty, didn't have Tomcat at hand.

If you need that functionality check [WebSphere Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html), which is as fast and lightweight as Tomcat, but is fully Java EE Web profile compliant. It has lots of useful features like JPA, EJBLite, JAX-RS already available if needed, without fighting with additional libraries configuration.

**UPDATE END**

I've checked on WebSphere Liberty, you need to create reference to lookup your persistence unit via JNDI. You have two options to create that:

- Use annotation at the class level
  In any of your servlets you need to define annotation using the follownig:

> `@PersistenceUnit(name="JPATestRef", unitName="UnitName")`
>     `public class JPATester extends HttpServlet {`
>      `...`

- Use entry in `web.xml`

> ```
> <persistence-unit-ref>
>   <persistence-unit-ref-name>JPATestRef</persistence-unit-ref-name>
>   <persistence-unit-name>UnitName</persistence-unit-name>
> </persistence-unit-ref>
> ```

Then you access it using the following code:

```
try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    System.out.println("looking EntityManagerFactory:");
    EntityManagerFactory emf2 = (EntityManagerFactory) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/JPATestRef");
    System.out.println("emf:2" + emf2);

} catch (NamingException e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a JNDI datasource in JPA, this should be specified in the persistence.xml, something like:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2">
        <persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/LCDS</non-jta-data-source>
    ...
```

Then you just have to create your EntityManagerFactory via [Persistence#createEntityManagerFactory(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String%29). If you want to recycle the EntityManagerFactory, this should be done outside of JNDI (e.g. as a ServletContext attribute). This is because Tomcat is not a Java EE server, only a servlet container: he is not able to inject the persistence unit.